# Load nested data from firestore to pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I want to work with nested data from my firestore database in pandas.

I'm able to load the not nested entries like this

```
db = firestore.client() 
pushes = db.collection('pushes').get()  
pushes_dict = list(map(lambda x: x.to_dict(), pushes))
dfPushes = pd.DataFrame(pushes_dict)
```

It shows everything on the first level perfectly.

But there is dfPushes['entities'] which has data looking like this within every cell of the column

```
[{'e': 'breaking news'}, {'e': 'cdc'}]
```

I now want to extract this data and create a new row for every found entity in the array. Kind of transpose in excel. The row should be filled up with other corresponding data which was in the row of the entities json array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will expand your `e` to new columns

```
pd.json_normalize(df, record_path=['entities'],  \
                  meta=['<parent field1>','<parent field2>', 'so on'])
```